# Software Advice for producing video ads

Tags: video, software, video-editor, software-recommendation

I am developing a web application and going to launch it soon. I am already done with the website, photos and brochures, and only the video presentation is missing. To present the app, I just want to show them the features in text and graphic form, sans the actors, locations and props. I want to produce the video taking inspiration from Oracle video ads like this [Oracle Exadata. Are You Ready?](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4qzFFBff34g) and this [Power Your HR Business Contribution With Oracle Human Capital Management](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WQs94hh9UDI)

Do you know how these videos were produced? Can you suggest some software that can produce videos like these? Thanks!

Comment: You're not looking for software, you're looking for a person, namely a motion graphics artist.

Answer (score 2):

That is motion graphics.  A program like Adobe After Effects in combination with Photoshop or Illustrator is ideal for producing such a video.  Something like Flash could also be used.

Note that it is very complicated to make something that good on your own.  There are however templates available for After Effects that you may be able to use.  Alternately, you could look for someone who knows how to do motion graphics and hire them to do something.

Comment: +1 -- if you want it to look professional, hire a professional.